# Is it possible to restore photos from Recently Deleted?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an app which works with Photo Gallery using PhotoKit.

Images are deleted via this function.

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets([asset as Any] as NSArray)
}, completionHandler: completion)
```

Is it possible to recover deleted assets from Recently Deleted smart album?